# Why does my embedded link not work in google app engine service?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a  app that is embedded in another page that is using IAP authentication   on google console it seems to be working fine when I sign in  normally but when I use incognito the embbed web app wont show.

```
import React from "react";

const page = props => {

  return <embed  src={"page.appstop.com"} width="100%" height="700px"/>
};
export default page;
```

```
   <main>
                    <Route path="/page" component={props => <page history={history}/>} />
                </main>
```

The main app and the embedded app have their own authentication  but I cant seem to get the embedded one to work in incognito mode and I am not sure why this is and how I can over come it. Does any one know what I should do and how I should do it ?

the error code I get is

```
Access to internal resource at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=4.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid+email&redirect_uri
=https://iap.googleapis.com/v1/oauth/clientIds/id 
:handleRedirect&code_challenge=D&code_challenge_method=S256&cred_ref=true&state= 
(redirected from 'https:page.app.appspot.com/manifest.json') from origin 
'https://page.app.appspot.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
accounts.google.com refused to connect.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the embedded link is being blocked by [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) probably because the Cookies are restricted in incognito.

You could test adding headers on your server code.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Acces-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Acces-Contorl-Allow-Methods','Content-Type','Authorization');
    next(); 
})
```

You may need to specify an explicit origin for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response-header value. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#:%7E:text=Credentialed%20requests%20and%20wildcards).